# generating udp packet using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Can anyone please help on how to fix the following issue:

```
def __init__(self,source, dest):
    self.source =  socket.inet_aton(source)
    self.dest =  socket.inet_aton(dest)
    self.sport = 68
    self.dport = 67
    self.length = 0
    self.udpchecksum = 0
    self.data = ''

def UDP(self):
    udp_hdr = struct.pack('!HHHH', self.sport,
    self.dport,
    self.length,
    self.udpchecksum)
   #Pseudo header
    psip = self.source
    pdip = self.dest
    reserved = 0
    proto = socket.IPPROTO_UDP
    tlen = len(udp_hdr) + len(self.data)
    pshdr = struct.pack('!4s4sBBH',
            psip,
            pdip,
            reserved,
            proto,
            tlen)
    pshdr = pshdr + udp_hdr+ self.data
    udp_checksum = checksum(pshdr)
    udp_hdr = struct.pack('!HHH',
              self.sport,
              self.dport,
              tlen)
              udp_checksum = struct.pack('H', udp_checksum)
    udp_hdr = udp_hdr + udp_checksum + self.data
    return udp_hdr

def checksum(data):
    s = 0
    n = len(data) % 2
    for i in range(0, len(data)-n, 2):
        s+= ord(data[i]) + (ord(data[i+1]) << 8)
    if n:
        s+= ord(data[i+1])
    while (s >> 16):
        s = (s & 0xFFFF) + (s >> 16)
    s = ~s & 0xffff
    return s
```

When I'm sending the packet using raw socket a got an error on wireshark says:

BAD UDP LENGTH

The Question is:
Is it the appropriate way to generate a UDP packet using raw socket ?

Comment: Is this a question about raw sockets specifically, or do you just need a high-level interface to send a packet over UDP? In the latter case `sock=socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM); sock.connect(dest); sock.send(msg)` should do just fine.

Comment: UDL length should be encoded in network byte order, it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: what i want here is to send a dhcp discover message, but when i concatenate the UDP packet with the generated DHCP discover packet, it says unknown bootp packet whereas if i send the dhcp discover packet without the generated UDP packet above, the packet is well known as a dhcp discover.
I think the problem is on my UDP packet

Comment: here is the socket object  `s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)` and here is how i sent the packet    `s.sendto(pkt,("255.255.255.255",67))`